# run project c# with .dll embebed, works if run from VS2010, dont works from executable

Tags: c#, dll

> i have one project in c#, in the project i add a file.dll, this work when i run the program from VS2010, but when i try to run form /bin/debug/myproject.exe it doesn't work, and just fail when the program use the file.dll  
>   i tried:  
>   file.dll configure its properties like:  
>   build action: Content
>   also  
>   build action: Embedded Resource
>   but still doesn't work...  
>   sorry for my english, hope you can help and understand my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to set the property "Copy local" to "true"?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is too broad. Be more concrete, which exception have you got?

Comment: the exception is: error:System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.  but the same process is succesful when y run myproject from VS2010 and dont show me any exception

Comment: Markus, yes i put in the property's file.dll:  "Copy to Output Direct: Copy Always"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the build action: none and copy to output dir: copy always or copy if newer?

Why do you don't add the dll as a reference (copy local: true if needed)? Or do you don't want to use it?

Comment: well... first: yes i used "none, and copy always", and the problem persist, now about add as reference, yes i tried, but show me a message that it couldnt, so this is the reason like i dont use it

Comment: What does the message say? Any reasons why the dll couldn't be added? The file.dll is in the output directory or not? 
If you can start the /bin/debug/myproject.exe you can debug your program (debug/attach to process) and maybe you'll see why your program is crashing. Hint: insert a Thread.Sleep(10000) at the beginning of your programm. So you'll have 10 seconds to attach to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the problem, my application communicates trough console with the file.dll , when i run mi project from VS this console is open default but when i execute the application from /bin/debug/myproject.exe this don't open any console, so the communitacion failure, so now i think the solution is create a console for this communitacion that running behind the application